# Wrong value of char array copy

Tags: c++

Everything works, No problems with compilation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    char chArray[30];
    char chArray2[] = "this is working";
    *chArray = *chArray2;

    cout << chArray;
    getch();
}
```

But...result is

[image]

and I don't know what I did wrong guys. Why is the output as shown. Please help :>

Comment: Your statement `*chArray = *chArray2;` has the same effect as `chArray[0] = chArray2[0]` (That's what the * does in this instance - it's short for 'the element pointed to by XX') You probably want to use strcpy..

Comment: Just use `std::string`.

Comment: You got the `t` right.

Comment: `main` does not return `void`. It returns `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`*chArray = *chArray2;` will just set the first array element, not the whole "string".

P.S. Didn't go offsite to look at the result. You should describe it in the question.

Comment: you have right but I must have 10 reputation to put picture inside question. Sorry, and one more question What can I do to working copy array ?

Answer (score 2):

Ah it's so easy to mistake C for C++...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string a;
    string b = "this is working";
    a = b;

    cout << a;
}
```

Notes:

- `conio.h`/`getch` aren't standard C++.
- C++ requires `main` return type to be `int`.

Comment: Dzięki ale potrzebowałem tablic sprawdzałem jak działają, ponieważ potrzebuje ich do budowania applikacji z winsock'iem a tam nie mogę przesyłać stringów ;/

Comment: @BartekMaciąg FYI: `string.c_str()`. And please use English, not Polish, so others can understand our discussion, too! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
char chArray[30];
```

This creates an array of 30 `char`s and has a base address which is same as `&chArray[0]` i.e the address of the 1st element of the array and is the same address that you get when when you do `chArray` ([array name acts as a pointer](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm))

```
char chArray2[] = "this is working";
```

You are creating a constant string literal assigning it to `chArray2` at the line of declaration. The array has base address which is same as `&chArray2[0]` and is the same when you do `chArray2`

`*chArray` will refer to the 1st element of the array and so will `*chArray2`

By using `*` you are assigning the value of 1st element of `chArray2` to `chArray` **not the address**.

AND you **can't/shouldn't** do that.

`chArray`  is not a pointer of type `char*` to which you can assign an address `char* p = chArray2`, but its of type `char(*chArray)[30]` . The address is automatically generated.

When you do `std::cout` it prints garbage because **nothing is assigned** to `chArray` yet except the 1st character (note there is no `\0` to mark the end of string so while printing you print garbage)
    *chArray = *chArray2;

You **need to use** `strcpy(chArray,chArray2);` to properly copy your `chArray2` to `chArray`

If you are using `c++` (as tagged), you can use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Its easier and better.

```
string chArray;
string chArray2 = "this is working";
chArray = chArray2;
```

**Sidenote:**

Make it [`int main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

Comment: Why the downvote? I want to know what's wrong so I can learn and rectify too

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `char chArray2[]` is not a constant string literal, it is a non-const character array. `"this is working"` is a constant string literal which gets copied into the chraracter array.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `chArray2` isn't a constant string literal, it's a character array initialized with the string literal.

Comment: Thanks for help I need this body ;D

Comment: @Hasturkun Now I get it

Comment: @Lundin Agree with that.

Comment: `strcpy` and C arrays are hardly a C++ way... Just sayin'.

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++ pointer the operator '&'denotes the address and the '*' denotes the value of pointer type.

In your case the code *chArray = *chArray2 assigns the character 't' to *chArray array.

So you are getting junk characters, because the string is not terminated with '\0' character.

Option 1:
you can use strcpy function to copy the strings.
strcpy(chArray, chArray2);

Option 2:
Both the variables shall be declared as pointers and shall be assigned with '=' operator.